# ошибка при установке TensorFlow.js (tfjs-node)

Tags: node.js, tensorflow

Не билдит библу tensorflow. Пробовал гуглить но у меня ничего не получалось, не с переустанвко node-gyp, не с переустановкой windows-build-tools, пробовал разные версии tensorflow и тоже ничего.
Делал все по примеру [туториала на сайте tensorflow](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-nodejs-codelab).

Вот ошибка которую мне выдает:

```
* Building TensorFlow Node.js bindings
node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v3/1.2.11/CPU-windows-1.2.11.zip
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@1.2.11 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp: D:\university\??\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\build\config.gypi not found (cwd: D:\university\??\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=D:\\university\\ИИ\\TS-baseball-pitch\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v3\\tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=D:\\university\\ИИ\\TS-baseball-pitch\\node_modules\\@tensorflow\\tfjs-node\\lib\\napi-v3" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=3" "--node_napi_label=napi-v3"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\university\ИИ\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=D:\university\ИИ\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v3\tfjs_binding.node --module_name=tfjs_binding --module_path=D:\university\ИИ\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v3 --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=3 --node_napi_label=napi-v3' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\university\ИИ\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\university\\ИИ\\TS-baseball-pitch\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\university\ИИ\TS-baseball-pitch\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается оно не хотело билдить из-за того что название папки в пути к проекту была на русском.